# Is there a way i can access "Script_fields" in custom "Script Context" used for sorting

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-5

In Sort_context while using custom Script. According to [documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/painless/6.8/painless-sort-context.html) i can access these.

1) **params (Map, read-only)**

2) **doc (Map, read-only)**

3) **_score (double read-only)**

Is there a way, I can access the results of Fields(here "kuchbhi") Created by **Script_Field** in the query, inside **Sort Context** in *algo_for_sorting*?

For Example in the script **algo_for_sorting** (custom painless script for sorting) i may write like

**fields['kuchbhi'][0]**.

My Query look like this.

```
GET hockey/_search
{
  "explain": true,
  "size": 20, 
  "query": {
    "match_all": {}
  },
  "stored_fields": [
    "_source"
  ],
  "sort": {
    "_script":{
      "type" : "number",
      "script" : {
        "id": "algo_for_sorting",
        "params":{
          "query":"linkedin"
        }
      },
      "order" : "desc"
    }
  },
  "script_fields": {
    "kuchbhi": {
      "script": {
        "id": "poca",
        "params": {
          "query" : "frolik"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**No you can't access script_fields from sort script or query script**

For example you can't access script_fields `kuchbhi` from the script `algo_for_sorting`. You have to copy the script_fields logic to the script algo_for_sorting

Comment: Thanks, for your answer. It means i have to run the script (the logic) two times. Once when creating the field, second when i need it inside 'algo_for_sorting'. Probably the reason is that sorting script runs before, Script_field is generated, isn't it?